# MySQL : insert only if another table condition ... AND retry if not

Tags: php, mysql

Tables

| product | review |
| --- | --- |
| product_id | product_id |
| status | author |
|  | text |

I select the minimum and maximum product_id's

```
$query_select = "SELECT MIN(product_id) as min_id, MAX(product_id) as max_id FROM product";
$res_select = $con->query( $query_select );
$row = $res_select->fetch_assoc();

$min_id = $row["min_id"];
$max_id = $row["max_id"];
```

And I enter values in another table with random product_id

```
array loop

$query_insert = "INSERT INTO review ( product_id, author, text) VALUES (" . rand( $min_id, $max_id ) . ",'" . $data[ "name" ] . "','" . $data[ "commentary" ] . "')";
```

Issue 1

BUT only insert if random `product_id` `status = 1` (I cannot use `WHERE status = 1` in query_select with MIN and MAX)

Issue 2

AND if random product_id `status = 0`, try another random `product_id` with `status = 1` ... without breaking loop

I tried INSERT SELECT, INSERT SELECT WHERE EXISTS, ...

Comment: Why can't you use `WHERE status = 1`?

Comment: product_id 1 status 1, product_id 2 status 0, product_id 3 status 0, 
product_id 4 status 1
...
where status = 1 
rand(1,4) 
may result in product_id 3 or 4

Comment: @MarcoM i did not get your comment, can you explain?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Sure. Between MIN and MAX product_ids there are product_ids with status = 0.  
No matter if I determine WHERE status = 1  
product_id 1 status 1 ( MIN )  product_id 2 status 0  product_id 3 status 0  product_id 4 status 1 ( MAX )

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a separate query to get min/max product IDs. Use a `JOIN` with the `product` table in an `INSERT ... SELECT`.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('
    INSERT INTO review (product_id, author, text)
    SELECT product_id, ?, ?
    FROM product
    WHERE status = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $data["name"], $data["commentary"]);
```

Then call `$stmt->execute()` in the insert loop.

Comment: @OP Note the use of [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) here

Comment: @Barmar Great ! prepared statements ;) I'll try and come back with a feedback ( 3:10AM here ) Thanks